# How do I find the size of mounted USB flash drive in C?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I have a flash drive device (/dev/sda1) mounted to /mnt on an embedded linux system (kernel 2.6.23). Using C how do I work out the size of the drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux, if you're not worried about portability (C doesn't know about drives, so any such specific code will be unportable), use `statfs()`:

```
  struct statfs fsb;

  if(statfs("/mnt", &fsb) == 0)
    printf("device has %ld blocks, each %ld bytes\n", fsb.f_blocks, fsb.f_bsize);
```

Answer (score 4):

Read and parse a number in device's sysfs entry. In your case,

1. Full device (all partitions and partition table): `/sys/block/sda/size`
2. Logical partition on this device: `/sys/block/sda/sda1/size`

The device does not have to be mounted yet.

Comment: The number is in blocks size. Therefore you have to multiply it with i.e. 512 to get it in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem using external tools, exec this :

`df -h | grep -i /dev/sda1`

using [popen](http://www.cs.uq.edu.au/~comp2303/Leslie_C_ref/C/FUNCTIONS/popen.html), and parse the resulting line with **strtok**.

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing something like that. The application is running on an embedded platform and would require too much resource to do the above.

Comment: `-h` is probably unnecessary here since the input will be read by program.  `-i` is also redundant due to case-sensitivity.  Other than that--a good LSB-conformant (i.e. portable) solution.